# Fatal Exception error in dynamic radio buttons

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view

i want to create the radio buttons dynamically from the database but the activity shows the error and crash. there is fatal exception main error and here is the logcat:

```
09-01 14:37:54.628: I/SurfaceTextureClient(2143): [0x40f0a7d8] frames:54, duration:1.018000, fps:53.007999
09-01 14:37:55.612: D/dalvikvm(2143): threadid=12: exiting
09-01 14:37:55.612: D/dalvikvm(2143): threadid=12: bye!
09-01 14:37:55.615: D/ActivityThread(2143): ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{418026e8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@41801eb {com.example.ecpvotesystem/com.example.ecpvotesystem.MainActivity}}
09-01 14:37:55.635: D/ActivityThread(2143): ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@41801eb8
09-01 14:37:55.693: D/dalvikvm(2143): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 375K, 4% free 16746K/17271K, paused 18ms, total 23ms
09-01 14:37:55.979: D/AndroidRuntime(2143): Shutting down VM
09-01 14:37:55.979: W/dalvikvm(2143): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ff2908)
09-01 14:37:55.999: E/AndroidRuntime(2143): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-01 14:37:55.999: E/AndroidRuntime(2143): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ecpvotesystem/com.example.ecpvotesystem.ResultActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
09-01 14:37:55.999: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
09-01 14:37:55.999: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
09-01 14:37:55.999: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
09-01 14:37:55.999: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
09-01 14:37:55.999: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-01 14:37:55.999: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
09-01 14:37:55.999: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
09-01 14:37:55.999: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-01 14:37:55.999: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-01 14:37:55.999: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
09-01 14:37:55.999: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
09-01 14:37:55.999: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-01 14:37:55.999: E/AndroidRuntime(2143): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
09-01 14:37:55.999: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3459)
09-01 14:37:55.999: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3330)
09-01 14:37:55.999: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3275)
09-01 14:37:55.999: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3251)
09-01 14:37:55.999: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at com.example.ecpvotesystem.ResultActivity.onCreate(ResultActivity.java:52)
09-01 14:37:55.999: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5020)
09-01 14:37:55.999: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
09-01 14:37:55.999: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
09-01 14:37:55.999: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     ... 11 more
```

and here is the code for java file:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy=new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

dbcon=DBConnection.instance(this);
dbcon.connect("ip:1433", "pas", "login", "db");
Context cntxt=getApplicationContext();

try {

    Thread.sleep(10);

    String city=getIntent().getExtras().getString("city");
    String choice=getIntent().getExtras().getString("choice");

    LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(cntxt);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ImageView iv=new ImageView(cntxt);
    RadioGroup.LayoutParams prams=new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    prams.setMargins(0, 2, 0, 2);


    RadioGroup rg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.RRG);

        rg=dbcon.GetResultList(rg,choice,city,iv,cntxt);

        ll.addView(rg);

        ((ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.RRG)).addView(ll);



} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

and following is the GetResultList() function with parameters which is called against it:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public LinearLayout GetResultList(RadioGroup rg,String choice,String city,ImageView iv,Context context) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

if(conn==null){

}
try{
    RadioButton rb;
    rg.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);

        Statement st=conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from AM_NATIONAL where ca_city="+city+ "order by cvg_count");

        while (rs.next()){
            rb=new RadioButton(context);
            rb.setId(rs.getInt(1));
            rb.setText(rs.getString(2)+"\n");
            rb.setText(rs.getString(3)+"\n");
            rb.setText(rs.getInt(8));

            byte[] photo=rs.getBytes(4);
            Bitmap bitmap;
            bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photo, 0, photo.length);
            iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            rb.setEnabled(false);
            rg.addView(iv);
            rg.addView(rb);


        }
        rs.close();
        st.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException e){

    }
   return rg;

   }
```

and here is the xml layout file:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context=".ResultActivity" >

 <ScrollView
     android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical" >

         <RadioGroup 
             android:id="@id/RRG"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

         </RadioGroup>

     </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>


 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it is not returning the rg and provide null. help me to solve this issue. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to add your RadioGroup to a new layout that you create dynamically before removing it from its existing layout...

```
ll.addView(rg);
```

The above line takes the RRG RadioGroup and adds it to the dynamically created LinearLayout, but it already exists within the LinearLayout defined in your xml layout.

Either create your RadioGroup dynamically (e.g. in code) or remove it from its parent before attempting to add it to your new layout e.g. try the following...

```
((LinearLayout)rg.getParent()).removeView(rg);
ll.addView(rg);
```

Comment: i want to show ll in the RRG radio group of the xml

Comment: i tried this by creating new radio group and it is working now thanks to identify the errors. thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

The error there:

```
ll.addView(rg);
((ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.RRG)).addView(ll);
```

You are trying to add `rg` into `ll` then `ll` into `rg`. What did you want to do?

Comment: i pas the rg to GetResultList as parameter as to create the dynamic radio buttons from database information and that will be add to radio group and function will return that radio group rg. that rg will assign to linear layout which is created as ll and then this will show in the RRG of the layout.

Comment: i want to show ll in the RRG radio group which is in the xml

Comment: If you want to put `ll` into `RRG` try to remove `ll.addView(rg);`.